# How do I sum the content of a list containing numpy arrays?

Tags: python, list, numpy

Consider the following code:

```
arr = np.array([1, 2, 32, 3, 3])

list1 = arr.tolist()
print(list1)
[1, 2, 32, 3, 3]
```

I want to create a sum of the entire content to get the following output

```
list_sum=[41]
```

Is there an elegant way to quickly do this?

Comment: That's not a list of NumPy arrays. `tolist()` performs a deep conversion, so you get a list of lists of ordinary Python ints, with no NumPy types involved in the output.

Comment: yes you are correct. I will correct the mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `numpy`'s native summing with an axis:

```
In [39]: arr.sum(axis=0)
Out[39]: array([3, 5, 6])
```

Comment: thanks in my example it would be sum(list1)=41